# C: copying data in a buffer in raw sockets (quite general)

Tags: c, memcpy

I am using raw sockets. I have received **packet** correctly.

```
unsigned char *rbuffer, ch, *packet; 
rbuffer=malloc(22);

ch=*(packet+sizeof(struct ethhdr)+sizeof(struct iphdr)+2);
printf("\tpacket_buffer[1]=%d",ch); //printing right as sent


memcpy(rbuffer,packet+sizeof(struct iphdr)+sizeof(struct iphdr)+1,22);
printf("\nrbuffer[1]=%d",rbuffer[1]); //printing wrong
```

Why is it so?

Any help
Thanks :)

Comment: Because %d treats your unsigned char pointer as a pointer to an integer, causing your number to be not what you expect?

Comment: Right and wrong are very undefined terms. You're printing a `char` with %d, which expects an int.

Comment: @o_weisman that's in first printf too!!

Comment: @littleadv right and wrong here refers to what I sent is same as what I am getting.

Comment: @user3542109 I'm sure that what you sent is what you're getting. I'm not sure that what you sent is what you're printing. In general, I suggest avoiding too much pointer arithmetics in one line. Temporary variables haven't killed anyone yet. Proper typing would help, too.

Comment: You getting offset in first one by `packet+sizeof(struct ethhdr)+...` and in second one is `packet+sizeof(struct iphdr)+...`.

Comment: solved it but would like to know the meaning of this line - **Temporary variables haven't killed anyone yet.**